# Connection In memory with "-"

Tags: security, symfony, yaml

I want to connect in memory some users.

It doesn't works when I use `ad-min`, but it works when I use `admin`

How can I connect with an user with a `-` inside??

```
in_memory:
    memory:
        users:
            admin: { password: pass, roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN' ] }
            ad-min: { password: pass, roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN' ] }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the [User subsection](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers) of the [security part of the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html),

> If your username is completely numeric (e.g. 77) or contains a dash
>   (e.g. user-name), you should use an alternative syntax when specifying
>   users in YAML:

It's then forbidden to do,

```
users:
    - { name: 77, password: pass, roles: 'ROLE_USER' }
    - { name: user-name, password: pass, roles: 'ROLE_USER' }
    - ...
```